# SqlException for datetime column

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following LINQ query :

```
var studentRecords = context.Students
                            .Include(i => i.StudentsAdmission)
                            .Where(w => !w.StudentsAdmission.Any() 
                                        || w.StudentsAdmission.Any(s => s.AdmissionDate == null || s.AdmissionDate == DateTime.MinValue))
                            .ToList();
```

The `AdmissionDate` column is defined as `[AdmissionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL`.

This query is throwing an error :

> Error Number:242,State:3,Class:16
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Read() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> ClientConnectionId:3d199aef-d03e-4041-82c8-87cfa6212098
> Error Number:242,State:3,Class:16

I have checked the table and the data seems to be right. What am I missing?

EDIT: I do not want to change the column to nullable because this will end up causing a lot of other changes.

Comment: Please add more information about your domain classes. 
Check `AdmissionDate` column type on the database it should be `datetime` or `datetime2`.
You can use `Where(P => P.AdmissionDate == default)` if everything is ok. No need to add nullability there.

Comment: Probably EF Core cannot translate `DateTime.MinValue` which has `00:00:00.0000000 UTC` but `datetime` min value is `January 1, 1753`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv How do I go about fixing it? I need to get records which in case any fields with AdmissionDate is not null/not default.

Comment: @RezaNoei default did not work, threw the same issue.

Comment: Well, what is the default value in the table? I mean which value is "no value"

Comment: I have used datetime my domains so many times. If you leave a `DateTime` property without any value, EF Core will automatically set it's value to `default` (or same `DateTime.MinValue`) which will be `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` in the `sql-server`.
I think there must be a configuration issue.

Comment: Please provide more information about your domains and your configurations.
@TheFallenOne

Comment: A DateTime can never be a null in c#.  So remove the test for null.  The default for DateTime (the min value) is 1/1/01.

Comment: @RezaNoei : the error is due to testing for NULL, so simply remove the test for null.

Comment: @jdweng is right. DateTime is a ValueType and it can't be null. If you gonna test it you should directly compare it against `default` or `DateTime.MinValue`. otherwise you should make it nullable.

Comment: Try assign to local variable `var minValue = new DateTime(1973, 1, 1)` and use this value in LINQ query, sorry I cannot test it right now.

Comment: You never followed up on the first comment. Provide a [mre]. Then we can talk. All of this goes nowhere without it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because DateTime.MinValue translates to 0001-01-01, a value outside the range SQL Server can handle.

Comment: The OP should check the actual data to see what value (if any) is used to represent a "no value" AdmissionDate and adjust the above as appropriate. Might be something like 1900-01-01.

Comment: Could `s.AdmissionDate < minValidAdmissionDate` ever be true for the define 1753-01-01 min date? Perhaps `<` should be `=` or `<=`.